# Client files location with node server?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying a stupid simple chat app per here: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

All good, except I figured I'd split the css and js out of the index.html file into separate files.  So I have a project folder that looks like this:

```
/myProject
  index.js
  index.html
  /node_modules
     /express
     /socket.io
```

So in the myproject folder, I created client folder and put an app.css and app.js in there:

```
/myProject
  /client
    app.css
    app.js
```

and switched my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/app.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/client/app.js"></script>
```

I restart the node server and run the index, however my chrome inspector has 404s on the `/client` files.

I tried moving the client folder into the node_modules folder (thinking that this must be where the html is getting it's socket.io ref from), but that doesn't do it.

When the node server starts, what local folder does it serve from (using Windows here), and how do I add other client side files?  I'm not supposed to be listing all these in the package dependencies am I?

Per the answer below, yes, using express (4.10.2)

Getting error:

> reference error: express is not defined

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on *.3000');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im assuming you using express.

So in order to serving static files in Express you need this

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

`app.use(express.static('client'));`

Hope this helps.

Comment: That would also require changing the URL's in the HTML to `/app.css` and `/app.js`

Comment: Yep..if all that will be in same directory. Read article. Your url would be just href="app.css"

Comment: You can also use `app.use('/client', express.static('client'))` to keep the `/client/` prefix in HTML.

Comment: I'm trying that but getting "express is not defined" and trying to work through that.  Express is installed and it works fine until I put that in the index.js

Comment: Well..that's different error. Show us index.js code.

Comment: just put it in the question, this worked before adding the `app.use` line (so I know express is installed), but not sure how to get that ref set up.  thanks

Comment: Add in index.js... var express = require('express'); var app = express(); All should work..And remove this line var app = require('express')();

Comment: Np..Glad that help.