# Node.js cannot find client-side files

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client, client-server

I have a simple node.js app:

`server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.static('client'));

// Start the express web server listening on 8080
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Service started on port 8080.');
});

// Serve the homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

`index.html`

```html
<html>
... irrelevant junk ...
<script src="js/client.js"></script>
</html>
```

However, when I run `node server.js` and open `localhost:8080`, the console complains that it can't find `http://localhost:8080/javascript/client.js`.

Obviously, I want it to be looking at `./javascript/client.js`, instead of rooted at the locahost addr -- how to resolve?

The folder hierarchy is simple:

```
.
├── index.html
├── server.js
├── js
    └── client.js
```

I've tried to change `public` to `client` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558596/client-files-location-with-node-server) but that didn't help.

Comment: Where exactly in your server file system is `client.js`?  Please show your server-side file hierarchy so we can see where both `client.js` is and where `server.js` is (since you're using paths relative to that on the server).  We can answer this in 5 seconds if we know where those two files are in your file system.

Comment: the html tries to load `src="js/client.js"` ... so why is the server complaining it can't find `javascript/client.js` - your code suggests that a request for `js/client.js` would be served from `./client/js/client.js` where `.` is the folder where `server.js` is

Comment: @jfriend00 added the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on where your files are located on the server, you should make three changes:

```
app.use(express.static("./public"));
```

And, in the client, use this:

```
<script src="/js/client.js"></script>
```

Then, move your client-side files below the server-side files into a root public directory like this:

```
.
├── index.html
├── server.js
├── public
    ├── js
        └── client.js
```

Without moving the client-side files into `public`, then you open up your server-side code to being read by the client (which you do not want).

---

Here's how this works:

The client requests:

```
http://localhost:8080/js/client.js
```

`express.static()` sees a request for:

```
 /js/client.js
```

It starts at the root of your public files and combines `/js/client.js` onto the public directory path which then creates the right path to access:

```
public/js/client.js
```

You could have made it work without moving the client-side files into the `public` directory hierarchy, by just doing this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
```

But, then that would have opened up all your server-side files to be read by the client which you really do not want.